# understanding MONEY() datatype with precision and scale

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I was going through some sample exam questions on this link:

> http://www.elearningexams.com/70-461-notes/page/2

and came across question no.1 below.

```
Which of the following datatypes has a fixed precision and a scale of six digits?

A. Double

B. Money

C. Int

D. Numeric

E. SmallInt

F. VarInt

G. Float

Answer is B. Money
```

I didn't understand how Money() can have a fixed precision and a scale of six digits. I went through this MSDN doc but didn't understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql

Can someone please explain with **some examples** and how precision and scale is measured in MONEY().
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number.

Therefore:

**MONEY** has a **precision** of 19 and a **scale** of 4

**SMALLMONEY** has a **precision** of 10 and a **scale** of 4

The **precision** and **scale** of the numeric data types besides decimal are **fixed**. The scale of MONEY data type is 4 (four decimal digits)
More on precision and scale [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In TSQL **smallmoney** has scale of 4 and fixed precision of 10

```
smallmoney: -214748.3648 to 214748.3647
```

**Money** has a scale of 4 and fixed precision of 19

```
money: -922337203685477.5808 to 922337203685477.5807
```

I therefore conclude that the answer is wrong (perhaps they meant smallmoney to be option B)

Comment: Precision is the total number of digits, not the number of digits left of the decimal point. Smallmoney is similar to `decimal(10,4)`, not `decimal(6,4)`.

Comment: According to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql). So **SMALLMONEY** would be similar to `decimal(10,4)`

Comment: Sorry, here's my intended comment: According to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql) **SMALLMONEY** would be similar to `decimal(10,4)`

Comment: i'm still confused with the answers posted above and below. . . precision bit and scale bit is still not clear

Comment: What @BaconBits stated is right. Precision is the total number of digits, for example (extracted from here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql)) the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.